# How do I loop through items in an array and still be able to interact with other buttons and UI elements in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to loop through items in an array and log the index of each item every few seconds when a button is pressed.

Whenever the button is pressed, I can't press other buttons or interact with the screen in any way until it's done looping through all the items.

How do I make this task run in the background so I can interact with other elements on the screen?

```
for(wallpaperUUID in p0.children){
    var wallpaperUUIDString = wallpaperUUID.key.toString()
    var indexOfImage: Int = wallpaperArray.indexOf(wallpaperUUIDString)

    Log.i("Index of Image", indexOfImage.toString())

     val time = measureTimeMillis {
         runBlocking {
              for(i in 1..100000) {
                   launch {
                        delay(2000L)
                   }
               }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: run the for loop on background thread

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) which means it blocks the current thread until its action is done.

What you need is `asynchronous call` for that you can use `Job` and `CoroutineScope` in a `Dispatchers.Default`

ex:

```kotlin
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) 

coroutineScope.launch {
   // Your code
}
```

You can also call `coroutineScope.cancel()` to cancel the work you're doing.

Comment: no problem, if you need info on `Coroutines` you should take a look at these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F63mhZk-1-Y&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE_PFBRHFB_aL5stMQg3smhL)